# node: using chai's expect.to.throw on a function that takes arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I need to call `expect().to.throw()` on a function that takes arguments.  For example, say I have the following:

```
var func = function(x) {
  if (x > 1) {
    throw new Error()
  } else {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
expect(func).to.throw()
```

This fails, because it calls `func` without an argument, meaning it will never throw an error.  But if I call `expect(func(2)).to.throw()`, I get `AssertionError: expected undefined to be a function`.  The function gets called and the return value is passed to `expect`.

How can I use `expect().to.throw()` and give the included function arguments.  Is the only way to do it with an anonymous function, like `expect(() => {func(2)}).to.throw()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is from the chai [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw):

> If you need to assert that your function fn throws when passed certain arguments, then wrap a call to fn inside of another function.

```
expect(function () { fn(42); }).to.throw();  // Function expression
expect(() => fn(42)).to.throw();             // ES6 arrow function
```

Comment: `bind()` is also a good option: `expect(fn.bind(null, 42)).to.throw()`